# Query to Move data from one column value in a table to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, import

I have a parents table in which there are fields family_situations and admin_notes. By mistake while uploading the CSV, I uploaded all admin_notes data in family_situations column. Is there any way I can move all data in family_situations to admin_notes. Please help.

parent.rb

```
def self.import(file)
            CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
                parent = Parent.find_or_update_or_create_by(
                    parent_1_firstname: row['parent_1_firstname'],
                    parent_1_lastname: row['parent_1_lastname'],
                    family_situation: row['family_situation'],
                                    )
    end
```

schema

```
create_table "parents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "parent_1_firstname"
    t.string "parent_1_lastname"
    t.text "family_situation"
    t.string "admin_notes"
end
```

when I try the below code in the rails console it throwns an error undefined method SET

```
UPDATE Parent SET admin_notes=family_situation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Parent.update_all"admin_notes=family_situation"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE new_table SET columnA = (SELECT columnB FROM old_table
 WHERE old_table.key_column = new_table.key_column);
```

If you need to update a column in one table based on the values in another, then you will need to figure out which column maps rows from one table to the other. In my example below, I'll call this column the key_column. The UPDATE command can look like the following:

```
 UPDATE new_table SET columnA = (SELECT columnB FROM old_table
 WHERE old_table.key_column = new_table.key_column);
```

is there is no reference key or where condition use it this way

```
 UPDATE new_table SET columnA = (SELECT columnB FROM old_table
 WHERE old_table.autoserial < highest number on new table i.e : 100000);
```

Comment: family_situation and admin notes are in the same table